# Trouble with CSS grid gap spacing

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I'm trying to build a relatively straightforward grid. I have 9 images that I want to be positioned in a 3 x 3 manner. Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/chris-c-thomas/pen/xxwWGRN

Unfortunately I get extra gap space in the row gaps as I think it's stretching some of the images. How do I go about fixing this?

HTML

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="photos-grid">
      <img class="photo photo-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x450.png" alt="">
      <img class="photo photo-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png" alt="">
      <img class="photo photo-3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png" alt="">

      <img class="photo photo-4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png" alt="">
      <img class="photo photo-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png" alt="">
      <img class="photo photo-6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x450.png" alt="">

      <img class="photo photo-7" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png" alt="">
      <img class="photo photo-8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x450.png" alt="">
      <img class="photo photo-9" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

SCSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.photos-grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.photo {
}
.photo-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.photo-2 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

.photo-3 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.photo-4 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / span 1;
}

.photo-5 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}

.photo-6 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / span 3;
}

.photo-7 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 5 / span 2;
}

.photo-8 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / span 3;
}

.photo-9 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 6 / span 1;
}
```

Comment: **The initial value for `align-self` and `justify-self` is `stretch` so the item will stretch over the entire grid area. The exception to this rule is where the item has an intrinsic aspect ratio, for example an image. In this case the item will be aligned to `start` in both dimensions in order that the image is not distorted.** [**ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Alignment/Box_Alignment_In_Grid_Layout#Self_alignment) So to remove the gaps you need `align-items:stretch;` on the container https://jsfiddle.net/tzmwsxf1/

Comment: I don't want the images to be stretched to fit a perfect 3x3. I want it be staggered like I have in my example. It's just there's a little extra padding as you can see.

Comment: Take look at the first image and the 2 images next to it, the first is `450px` in height, the other two are `150px` and `300px` respectively. those two images height's together should equal to the first one and fit perfectly without any gaps, However you've add `grid-gap: 20px;` which add to the total height of the two images on the right. So if the first image had  `20px` more this won't be an issue. You can't leave this to the browser to decided, you must be the one who decided, Either stretch the images or find a much more suitable solution to your liking.

Comment: @ZohirSalak 's last comment explains the reason for the gaps, and first comment provides a solution to the problem. Another approach would be to wrap the images in divs, making those divs the grid items. Then add `display: flex` to the items, causing the images to take full height of the grid cell. It's not much different than Zohir's approach, but it's not entirely clear what you want either. https://codepen.io/mbb7774/pen/LYpdpzL?editors=1100

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this layout (Masonry Layout) using CSS `column-count` on parent container.

Read more about CSS columns: 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-count/

Find more details on browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=column-count

Understanding Masonry Layout: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/

Note: This answer is not to discourage using CSS `display:grid`, however an attempt to simplify the CSS.

```css
.photos-grid {
  column-count: 3;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.photos-grid img {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .photos-grid {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .photos-grid {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="photos-grid">
  <img class="photo photo-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x450.png" alt="">
  <img class="photo photo-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png" alt="">
  <img class="photo photo-3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png" alt="">

  <img class="photo photo-4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png" alt="">
  <img class="photo photo-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png" alt="">
  <img class="photo photo-6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x450.png" alt="">

  <img class="photo photo-7" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png" alt="">
  <img class="photo photo-8" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x450.png" alt="">
  <img class="photo photo-9" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x150.png" alt="">
</div>
```